# How do i add faces (subdivision)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I'm a beginner on blender and im modeling this character for a game im making but i have a problem.
I need to remove some "faces" (i'm not sure if they are called faces) to make the shape for the eyes but to make a good shape for them i need to remove not just a big face but i need more and smaller ones, so i wanted to ask if someone can help me do that.

[image: What i need]

[image: what im trying to achieve]

Comment: Hello, are you sure that you need more faces? Maybe show a drawing of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: i just added it

Comment: So i'm not sure why you need more faces to do the eyes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need more topology, here is a proposition of topology for your head, I began with a subdivided cube (*Smoothness* at 1), then remove some faces and extruded inwards:

[image]